# Upload a file in any specific subfolder of sharepoint online C# (CSOM)

Tags: csom

I am trying to send a file (Test.docx) to a specific folder under document library in sharepoint online. The folder name is "new" which is under a "Test" folder i.e. Documents/Test/new. Now, there could be additional subfolder under "new" folder where I want to send that file.
I have tried with attached code, but it is not working. I can send file to "Test" folder with current code but not in subfolder of it in "new", and getting execption like "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: File Not Found". Is there a simple way to do that with my current code? Thank you!

```
            using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://myDomain.sharepoint.com/sites/siteName"))
            {
                clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securePassword)

                Web web = clientContext.Web;
                FileCreationInformation fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
                fileCreationInformation.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
                fileCreationInformation.Url = "Test.docx";  
                List documentLibrary = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");  //get document library
                Folder destinationFolder = null;
                string destinationSubFolder = subFolder;  

                if (destinationSubFolder == "")
                {
                    destinationFolder = documentLibrary.RootFolder;
                }
                else
                {
                    destinationFolder = documentLibrary.RootFolder.Folders.GetByUrl("new"); 
                    destinationFolder.Update();
                }

                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = destinationFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);

                clientContext.Load(documentLibrary);
                clientContext.Load(uploadFile);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            }
```

Comment: Is there any update ? Did the code in the answer work to upload file into sub folder ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple with to generate the FileCreationInformation.Url with Path.Combine method:

```
                var uploadFilePath = "D:\\Test.docx";
                FileCreationInformation fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation
                {
                    Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(uploadFilePath),
                    Url = System.IO.Path.Combine("Shared Documents/Test/New", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploadFilePath)),
                    Overwrite =true

                };

                var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
                var uploadFile = list.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileCreationInformation);
                ctx.Load(uploadFile);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

The default "Documents" library should use "Shared Documents" as path.

Reference:

[How to upload a file in a Sharepoint library subfolder using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707649/how-to-upload-a-file-in-a-sharepoint-library-subfolder-using-c/25709088)